# ¿Por qué mi App no me está direccionando a mis container?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

Estoy usando react-router-dom, y primero me daba un error:

> export 'Switch' (imported as 'Switch') was not found in 'react-router-dom' (possible exports: BrowserRouter, HashRouter, Link, MemoryRouter, NavLink, Navigate, Outlet, Route, Router, Routes, UNSAFE_LocationContext, UNSAFE_NavigationContext, UNSAFE_RouteContext, createRoutesFromChildren, createSearchParams, generatePath, matchPath, matchRoutes, renderMatches, resolvePath, unstable_HistoryRouter, useHref, useInRouterContext, useLinkClickHandler, useLocation, useMatch, useNavigate, useNavigationType, useOutlet, useOutletContext, useParams, useResolvedPath, useRoutes, useSearchParams)

Según he investigado, a partir de la versión V6 del react-router-dom se debía cambiar Switch por Routes... Ahora este es mi código pero igual no funciona el ruteo de la app.

```
import logo from "./logo.svg";
import "./App.css";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import { HomeContainer } from "./container/home";
import { ListContainer } from "./container/list";
import { DetailContainer } from "./container/detail";

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<home />} componet={HomeContainer} />
        <Route path="/" element={<list />} componet={ListContainer} />
        <Route path="/" element={<product />} componet={DetailContainer} />
        Hola soy una app
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Incluyo la foto del VSC así ven la distribución de las carpetas y archivos.

[image: Esta es la foto de mi vsc]

Comment: Tu propiedad `componet` está mal escrita... y ahora usa es una propiedad llamada `element`

Comment: Hola, lo estoy colocando asi y aun no funciona.
<Route path="/" element={<home />} Element={HomeContainer} />
Si coloco element con la e minuscula me da error vsc

Comment: Ya leiste la documentacion de como funciona la propiedad `element`?

Comment: la verdad no, ahora lo busco, estoy aprendiendo React y aun estoy aprendiendo a interpretar la documentación.